# Automating Gmail login in Python

Tags: python, gmail

I am writing a Python program that can login Gmail.

The purpose of this program is to check whether the username/password combination exists and is correct.

Since this program is to test the the username/password combination existence, it's no need to know any mail contents in Gmail.

The input of this program is a **username** and **password**.

The output of this program is either

> successful login

or

> login failure

Login failure could be:

1. existing username+wrong password
2. nonexisting username

My idea is to login Gmail first. Afterward, when login failure, the gmail webpage will show particular message on the login webpage. I can parse the webpage content and check whether it has that particular message.

However, I still have no idea how to login Gmail in Python. Please let me know which module can be used or write me a small piece of sample code.

Comment: well, may I ask why would you like to do that?..AFAIK it's not that easy. after the 3rd or 4th wrong attempt to login, gmail starts to ask you more questions..

Comment: As @Acorbe said, trial/error login is probably a bad idea. Also, parsing the webpages = really bad idea.

Comment: It's part of my research. So, what if I know correct username and password? Which module can be used to login Gmail?

Comment: @WilHall I know they could be bad ideas, but I don't know how to do better...

Comment: Apart from anything else, no decent login system will ever tell you the difference between nonexistent username and existing username/wrong password: it's a huge security hole. In Django, they spent quite some time recently rewriting things because there was a timing difference between the two cases, and they didn't even want to expose that much.

Comment: There's no Gmail-specific module I'm aware of, but urllib or the like can be used to submit the login form. Note that you shouldn't be at all surprised if Google starts asking you to solve captchas or just blocks your IP altogether and marks your site as a phishing site in their index, because under no circumstances should you have an end user's Gmail username and password.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This kind of things are like *prohibited*, that's why things like OAuth or OpenID are created. This kind of things permit the user to login **without** entering *username* and *password*. So be careful.

Comment: what if I know correct username and password? Which module can be used to login Gmail?

Comment: This is not a python question, you just need to know how to do internet requests, so you can make a request directly to the Google page.

Comment: Can you give me some keywords?

Comment: From my experience, i have tested this thing but not directly. I wanted to use a service of Google (Google Docs). Google gives you a **Docs API** and then you have to know the credentials to your account to use the functions.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea:

Why don't you try to send an email from the account and see if it sends? You can do this with `smtplib` in the python standard module. There's code examples [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/14/how-to-send-email-with-python/). You'll have to look into the doc of the module, but it looks like an exception is thrown if the login fails, which should contain the details you're interested in.

In edit:

I dug up this bit of code that I wrote to do exactly that. You'll need to put a `try/catch` around the bit at the bottom to detect erroneous login credentials.

```
# Subject
now = dt.datetime.now().ctime()
subject = 'Change to system on %s' % now

# Body
body = 'Subject: %s,\n' % subject
body += 'On %s, a change to the system was detected. Details follow.\n\n' % now

relevantFiles = list(set([x.file for x in relevantChunks]))
for file in relevantFiles:

    fileChunks = [x for x in relevantChunks if x.file == file]
    for chunk in fileChunks:
        body += '****** Affected file %s. ' % chunk.file
        <some other stuff>

server = smtp.SMTP(args.host) # host = smtp.gmail.com:<port> look this bit up
server.starttls()
server.login(args.username, args.password)
server.sendmail(args.sender, args.recipient, body)
server.quit()
```

---

As an aside, I'm not quite sure why this question was down-voted, or even what it takes to be down-voted other than the fact that you asked the wrong question.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib

msg = MIMEText("Hello There!")

msg['Subject'] = 'A Test Message'
msg['From'] = 'username@gmail.com'
msg['To'] = 'username@gmail.com'

s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
s.starttls()  ##Must start TLS session to port 587 on the gmail server
s.login('username', 'passsword') ##Must pass args gmail username & password in quotes to authenticate on gmail
s.sendmail('username@gmail.com',['username@gmail.com'],msg.as_string())

print("Message Sent")
```