# Gmail Login API with username and password in python

Tags: python, django, google-api, google-workspace

I have `username` and `password` of gmail account, I need **API** to automatically login to gmail from my python code.

I have tried using [smtplib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524340/automating-gmail-login-in-python)

```
import smtplib
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
server.starttls() 
username="test@gmail.com"
password="test"
server.login(username, password)
server.quit()
```

I am getting `smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError` error

Comment: What have you tried? Please post the code that you have tried? Please post the error also

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: maybe this SO answer will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852128/smtpauthenticationerror-when-sending-mail-using-gmail-and-python or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147455/how-to-send-an-email-with-gmail-as-provider-using-python

Comment: do we have API for gmail login?

Answer (score 0):

Go to [Google account security settings](https://myaccount.google.com/security?pli=1) and login to your account.

You need to scroll down and turn the options "Allow less secure apps" to on.